# Can't install kdenlive and kdeconnect, 403 forbidden

Tags: apt

I have this problem: I can't succeed in installing kdeconnect and kdenlive.

I get error 403 forbidden all the time.

Here's my output from terminal: http://pastebin.com/raw/6HFzfMVu

Anyone else had this error? I tried cleaning cache packages, --fix-missing, updating repos etc. but with no success. I also tried adding kdenlive repo but still get the same error. Works for other software.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

From the output, it looks like you are trying to download packages from the `universe` repository. This repository is maintained by Ubuntu community members and not by Canonical. **It's not reviewed by the Ubuntu security team either, so proceed at your own risk.**

`403` error can sometimes mean that the resource is no longer available, such as when a mirror gets taken down (either permanently or temporarily for maintenance). You might want to consider just waiting and seeing if the server comes back online in a few hours.

It looks like URLs without the `ba` prefix do currently resolve. So you might want to consider either manually downloading the packages using your web browser or changing your sources list (`etc/apt/sources.list`) to a working mirror.

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like a server issue.](https://askubuntu.com/a/308348/49899) Try using another country's repositories?

1. `sudo apt install software-properties-gtk`
2. Open "Software & Updates" in the Applications menu
3. Choose country server from the dropdown menu